# Why am I getting 400 error from FB's Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a FB app, which uses FB.api() from its JS SDK to post a message on user's feed. The issue is, I get 400 error instead.

(Please note many data have been modified for privacy)

The request was sent to URL:-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/?access_token=178486488887736|2.AQCDILuiyM-wBx8.3600.1313269200.1-1000|_z6EB7Ebp6Bxgf-ss
```

Request header:-

```
Host: graph.facebook.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: datr=IezG1St6azJsvDL; lu=wgWUTDTuiTLJXgPI8A; locale=en_US;  app_id=178486488887736; s=Aa7YfcM3PxNBg; L=2; act=1313261419%2F1; presence=EM31p_5f1B01179550304F5122K0H0U0OQ0EsF0CEblFDacF0EutF0PCC; c_user=100001304; sct=1313128632; xs=60%3Aa1c1753e6a6abd0fe7b23bfe4; p=167; _e_zzrj_3=%5B%22zzrj%22%2C1313261446%2C%22act%222Fyourmemorablestatus%2F%22%2C%7B%22ft%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22gt%22%3A%7B%22tti_ms%22%3A5464%2C%22app_id%22%3A178486488887736%2C%22is_early_flush%22%3Afalse%2C%22browser%22%3A%22Firefox%205%22%7D%7D%2C0%2C16%5D
```

The request used POST method. Post data was:-

```
Referer: http://connect.facebook.net/rsrc.php/v1/yK/r/RIxWozDt5Qq.swf
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length: 1993

access_token=1784864.1-1000011Ebp6Bxgf-ssENEpia7iPE&message=My%20memorable%20status%20messages%20%3A-)%0A%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%0A%0A%EF%BF%BD%20blog.applegrew.com%20and%20cink.applegrew.com%20both%20are%20now%20down.%20Moved%20them%20today%20to%20a%20new%20%22cloud%22%20based%20system%2C%20and%20now%20they%20are%20up%20in%20the%20air%20somewhere.%20Raised%20tickets%20against%20my%20service%20provider.%0A%0A%EF%BF%BD%20Check%20out%20the%20google%20home%20page%20today%2C%20and%20pluck%20the%20strings!%20%3A)%0A%0A%EF%BF%BD%20wow%20mallu%20girls%20r%20beautiful.%0A%0A%EF%BF%BD%20My%20Ctrl%2C%20C%2C%20V%20keys%20have%20started%20to%20wear%20out.%0A%0A%EF%BF%BD%20Developers%20are%20users%20too.%20People%20tend%20to%20forget%20that.%20%3A(%0A%0A%EF%BF%BD%20Once%20a%20wise%20one%20said%3A%20Bugs%20can%20neither%20be%20created%20nor%20destroyed%2C%20it%20has%20always%20existed%20and%20will%20come%20around%20in%20different%20manifestations.%0A%0A%EF%BF%BD%20unzip%2C%20strip%2C%20touch%2C%20finger%2C%20grep%2C%20mount%2C%20FSCK%2C%20more%2C%20yes%2C%20unmount%2C%20sleep%20.....%0A%0AThese%20are%20all%20Linux%20commands.%0A%0A%EF%BF%BD%20%EF%BF%BD%20Tonight%20going%20to%20Bryan%20Adam%20concert!%0A%0A&pretty=0&sdk=joey
```

Response header:-

```
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
P3P: CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
Pragma: no-cache
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#1) An unknown error occurred"
X-FB-Rev: 422152
Set-Cookie: _e_zzrj_3=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
X-FB-Server: 10.62.1.41
X-Cnection: close
Date: Sat, 13 Aug 2011 19:43:26 GMT
Content-Length: 78
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I found the problem. In FB message can be max 420 characters long (including spce etc.). I wish FB responded with a more humane error.